# MiniTest and non-Latin test description

Tags: ruby, testing, unicode, utf-8, minitest

Ruby 1.9 has got cool Unicode support, yeah?

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

describe "test" do
  it "α β γ δ & a b c d" do
    (1+1).must_equal 3
  end
end

# 1) Failure:
# test_0001__a_b_c_d(TestSpec) [test.rb:7]:
# Expected 3, not 2.
```

Where are my non-Latin letters? I should always write my tests in my horrible English?

Because I can define methods with any Unicode symbol:

```
def α_β_γ_δ_a_b_c_d
  puts "geeeek"
end

α_β_γ_δ_a_b_c_d
#=> "geeeek"
```

**PS** My question seems to be not clear. I want to ask how to make minitest's failure description to show my non latin definitions.

Comment: Downvoted and vote to close. This is not a question, it's a rant. Rants belong on blogs, SO is for questions.

Comment: It is a question. I was trying to ask how can I return all unicode letters at failure description

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag I've updated my question to be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is about [regexp used here](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/spec.rb#L194). it shows utf-8 characters after monkey patching `/\W+/` with `/\s+/`.

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class MiniTest::Spec < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def self.it desc = "anonymous", &block
    block ||= proc { skip "(no tests defined)" }

    @specs ||= 0
    @specs += 1

    # regexp /\W+/ replaced with /\s+/
    name = "test_%04d_%s" % [ @specs, desc.gsub(/\s+/, '_').downcase ]

    define_method name, &block

    self.children.each do |mod|
      mod.send :undef_method, name if mod.public_method_defined? name
    end
  end
end

describe "test" do
  it "α β γ δ & a b c D" do
    (1+1).must_equal 3
  end
end

#   1) Failure:
# test_0001_α_β_γ_δ_&_a_b_c_d(test) [forwarding.rb:24]:
# Expected: 3
#   Actual: 2
```